# Dialog and displaying it in a TextView

Tags: android, dialog, textview

I´ve a Dialog where I can select several things, in my example ingredients for a pizza.
I want to choose/select more than one item. But everytime I run the app, I can select more than one but it displays only one. 
Here´s my code, I overlooked it more then once but couldn´t find my mistake.
I hope you can help me.
Thanks in advance ;)

```
private void pizzaBelagDialog() {
    // Variablen
    final ArrayList<Integer> arrayBelag = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    final String[] strBelaege = { "Hühnchen", "Pepperoni", "Pilze",
            "Zwiebeln", "Speck", "Oliven", "Ananas", "Pommes", "Soße",
            "Meeresfrüchte" };

    // Process
    strBelag = "\nBelag:\n";
    dialogBuilder.setTitle("Wähle deinen Belag aus");
    dialogBuilder.setMultiChoiceItems(strBelaege, null,
            new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which,
                        boolean isChecked) {

                    if (isChecked) {
                        arrayBelag.add(which);
                    } else if (arrayBelag.contains(which)) {
                        arrayBelag.remove(Integer.valueOf(which));
                    }
                }
            });
    dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Ok",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    for (int intLoop = 0; intLoop < arrayBelag.size(); intLoop++) {
                        strBelag = strBelaege[(Integer) arrayBelag
                                .get(intLoop)] + ", ";
                    }

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Belag wurde ausgewählt.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                    Display();

                }
            });
    dialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Belag wurde nicht ausgewählt.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });
    // Output
    AlertDialog dialogPizzaBelag = dialogBuilder.create();
    dialogPizzaBelag.show();

}
```

Syntac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In every loop you override your variable strBelag. You should use this:
 `strBelag += your code + ", ".` This way you keep the value you added in the previous loop and don't change it.